# Troubles establishing connection with wvdial - Invalid dial command error

Tags: ppp, mobile, wvdial

I am trying to run internet via HUAWEI E3372 on Debian. It worked on Windows but did not work on Debian.The error is this:

```
ATDT*99#
ERROR
--> Invalid dial command.
wvdial: utils/wvtask.cc:303: static int WvTaskMan::yield(int): Assertion
*current_task->stack_magic == WVTASK_MAGIC' failed.
Aborted
```

Here you are the issue info:

*wvdial.conf*

```
root@debian:/home/b# cat /etc/wvdial.conf
[Dialer orange]
Modem = /dev/ttyUSB1
Phone = *99#
Username =;
Password =;
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet","",0,0
Auto DNS = on
root@debian:/home/b#
```

*dmesg | grep tty*

```
root@debian:/home/b# dmesg | grep tty
[    0.000000] console [tty0] enabled
[    4.288912] usb 2-8: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[    4.288990] usb 2-8: GSM modem (1-port) converter now attached to ttyUSB1
root@debian:/home/b#
```

*wvdial orange*

```
root@debian:/home/b# wvdial orange
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet","",0,0
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet","",0,0
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: ATDT*99#
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATDT*99#
ERROR
--> Invalid dial command.
wvdial: utils/wvtask.cc:303: static int WvTaskMan::yield(int): Assertion `*current_task->stack_magic == WVTASK_MAGIC' failed.
Aborted
root@debian:/home/b#
```

*lsusb*

```
root@debian:/home/b# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Modem/Networkcard
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 0bf8:1004 Fujitsu Siemens Computers 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
root@debian:/home/b#
```

### UPDATE

The configuration worked and internet got present actually. It was empty `resolve.conf` simlink so I copied `/etc/ppp/resolve.conf` one and  it worked.

Anyway **the error still remains** and I would like to get rid of it.

Also note that I am doing all with `Network Manager` service disabled.

Comment: Welcome to U&L , What is the output of `nmcli c` , just the line which give the information of your gsm connection.

Comment: Various distros have bug reports out on the issue. Effectively you are doing nothing wrong - it is a known issue with the wvstreams libraries. The solution is to recompile yourself... you'll have to Google it - "wvdial current_task->stack_magic failed". Eg. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=812651

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the huawei E3372. I am on a raspberry pi (4) however.
I solved it by adding
`max_usb_current=1`
to /boot/config.txt. Apparently
the E3372 silenty fails ("ERROR") when it does not get enough power and wvdial does not have any idea about it and just reports the "invalid dial command".
Apparently the E3372 is power hungry on TX and causes this.